# ffmpeg black screen recording

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

When I record my desktop or recording video with ffmpeg it generates a black video.
My operating system is Ubuntu 18:04 bionic kernel 4.16

Here is the command I'm using :

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 640x480 -i :1.0+10,20 -vf format=pix_fmts=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

Comment: Does recording into a file work?

Comment: @Hermann not working  just a black video

Comment: Are you sure you want to grab from `:1`? What does `ffmpeg -video_size 640x480 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -c:v libx264 -crf 16 -t 10 /tmp/test.mp4` do for you? Any interesting output on the console?